# How do I add the Parameter chosen to the report title in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

It looks like I can only get the value which is an ID that I'm passing to the linked report. It looks like I can only use Parameters in the report title expression instead of a DataSet field. If I add a parameter then the user would need to be involved and I just want it to take the text that the user chose in the drop down. It is a school_id "11" field that I'm passing to the linked report but the user is chosing the school_abb "AN" and that is what I want to display in the report header. 
This is the expression now: `="Printer Usage Report" + " - " + Parameters!SchoolAbb.Value`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I figured this out. Changed the .Value to .Label in expression builder.